# Ambiguity about tabpanel tabPosition:left

Tags: javascript, extjs, tabs, vertical-alignment, extjs5

### This is the test code:

```
Ext.define('App.TabsWin', {
    extend: 'Ext.Window',

    width: 600,
    height: 400,
    layout: 'fit',
    autoShow: true,
    viewModel: true,

    initComponent: function() {
        Ext.apply(this, {
            width: 740,
            items: [{
                xtype: 'tabpanel',
                reference: 'tabpanel',
                border: false,
                defaults: {
                    bodyPadding: 10,
                    autoScroll: true,
                    closable: true,
                    border: false
                },
                tabPosition: 'left',
                tabRotation: 0,
                items: [{
                    title: 'Tab 1',
                    icon: null,
                    glyph: 42,
                    html: 'long text'
                }, {
                    title: 'Tab 2',
                    icon: null,
                    glyph: 70,
                    html: 'extra long text'
                }, {
                    title: 'Tab 3',
                    icon: null,
                    glyph: 86,
                    html: 'long text'
                }]
            }]
        });

        this.callParent();
    }
});
Ext.create('App.TabsWin');
```

If you run [the code](http://dev.sencha.com/extjs/5.0.0/examples/kitchensink/?theme=crisp#advanced-tabs) in browser's console it works as expected but if you run that code tabs are on left side but not horizontally aligned.

Can anyone explain what's happening or how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean by "run in browsers' console"?

I haven't found any problems on the examples site.

It can be that if you copy & paste the above code to the browser console the required css styles are not loaded so the display can look weird/corrupted.

Use https://fiddle.sencha.com for playing with a code, it has all what's needed.

Comment: Problem was in extJs build version. It didn't work in Ext JS 5.0.0.736 Crisp but it works for newer build Ext JS 5.0.0.970 Crisp. Your link helped me to make this sure. Now is is working!